# Blazor's OnInitializedAsync event fires before DOM is finished

Tags: blazor-client-side

I'm currently working on a hosted/client Blazor WebAssembly app, which when initially run works fine.

In the 'OnInitializedAsync' method of the page being rendered is a javascript call to retrieve the width of an html element on the page. If I set a breakpoint in the javascript function, on initial app run the browser is displaying the rendered page and the element properties are correctly retrieved. However, when I refresh the browser page, when the breakpoint is hit the browser hasn't finished rendering the page and so the element's width is zero.

Can anyone tell me why this is and how I can fix the problem?

```
<div @ref="_carPanelWidth">
    ....
</div>

@code {

    private ElementReference _carPanelWidth;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await base.OnInitializedAsync();

        var carPanelWidth = await JsRuntime.InvokeAsync<int>("utilityFunctions.getElementWidth", new object[] { _carPanelWidth });

        StateHasChanged();
    }
}

window.utilityFunctions = {

    getElementWidth: function (element) {
        return element.offsetWidth;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I deal with a similar situation when rendering grids.  It causes a flashiness which looks unprofessional.

What I do is mark the html elements as hidden and later show them, when I know everything is loaded.  This completely eliminates flash, if that is the problem you are having.

```
<div id="table_id_div" style="visibility:hidden">
```

I use interopt to apply the DataTable.com stuff to the table and when that is complete the javascript runs...

```
$("#" + tableName + "_div").attr('style', 'visibility : visible');
```

This seems to do the trick.

Comment: Thank you for the info Bob, it's appreciated, but for my particular problem not an approach I can use. For the time being I've put the code in a loop and wait until the element has a width - I'm hoping for a better solution.

Comment: Understood. If I think of anything else I’ll let you know. 

The solution is working for me but I agree it’s not ideal.